# Uncaught ReferenceError;'abc' not defined in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html table with button. When click the button I call ajquery function which will do a GET call to my backend service.

Html page rows created as follows;

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Clients</title>
</head>
<body>
<table style="width:100%" id="clients_data">
<caption>Clients</caption>
  <tr>
    <th>Clients</th>
    <th>Number of Sites</th> 
    <th>Reset the Processing</th> 
  </tr>
  </table>

<!-- --Java script Functions  -->

<script>
function loadCustomers() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/cache/getCustomers',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var rows = [];
            $.each(data,function(id,value) {
                rows.push('<tr><td><a href="clientSiteInfo.html?client='+id+'">'+id+'</td><td>'+value+'</td><td><button type="button" onclick="reset('+id+')">Reset</td></tr>');
            });
            $('table').append(rows.join(''));
        }
    });
};


function reset(id) {
    alert(id)
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/cache/reset?clientName='+id,
        success: function(data) {
          alert("Reset success")
        }
    });
};

window.onload = loadCustomers;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

my reset function is like;

```
function reset(id) {
    alert(id)
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/cache/reset?clientName='+id,
        success: function(data) {
          alert("Reset success")
        }
    });
};
```

When I try to click button, I expect it has to pass '**id**' value to my **reset() function**

When click button I get;

```
 ReferenceError: testClient is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):1)
onclick @ (index):1
```

What Im doing wrong here?

Comment: Where is closing `</a>` tag at code at Question?

Comment: Can you show the part of your code that references testClient?  That's where you're hitting the error.

Comment: Nothing in code shown has anything to do with `testClient`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the rows:

```
// This is your code
$.each(data,function(id,value) {
  rows.push('<tr><td><a href="clientSiteInfo.html?client='+id+'">'+id+'</td><td>'+value+'</td><td><button type="button" onclick="reset('+id+')">Reset</td></tr>');
});
```

you add the `id` to the `onclick` attribute of the button. It'll look like this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="reset(testClient)">
```

You want it to look like this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="reset('testClient')">
```

Without those extra quotes, you aren't passing a string, you're passing the value of a variable (which is never defined).

The solution is to add those quotes to the HTML template:

```
$.each(data,function(id,value) {
  rows.push('<tr><td><a href="clientSiteInfo.html?client='+id+'">'+id+'</td><td>'+value+'</td><td><button type="button" onclick="reset(\''+id+'\')">Reset</td></tr>');
});
```

Comment: Thanks that works.Understood my mistake.